# MsRdpClient - open with querystring parameters

Tags: asp-classic, rdp, request.querystring

I'm currently trying to open an MsRdpClient connection in a web browser by opening a new tab and passing it dynamic server names. However, the following code doesn't seem to work and I can't dynimically populate any of the required values, namely servername and available screen width and height.

```
resWidth = request.querystring("width")
    resHeight = request.querystring("height")

    MsRdpClient.DesktopWidth = resWidth
    MsRdpClient.DesktopHeight = resHeight

    MsRdpClient.Width = resWidth
    MsRdpClient.Height = resHeight
    MsRdpClient.server = request.querystring("fqdn")

    MsRdpClient.username = "username"
    MsRdpClient.AdvancedSettings.ClearTextPassword = "password"

    MsRdpClient.AdvancedSettings2.RDPPort = "3389"
    MsRdpClient.Connect
```

I'm not really sure where to go from here. I see it's been asked on a few boards but no one has seem to come up with an answer. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Below is the script I ended up using. putting the required variables in via scriptlets is what did the trick. i.e. the "<%=fqdn%>"

```
resWidth = (screen.AvailWidth - 45)
resHeight = (screen.AvailHeight - 150)        

MsRdpClient.DesktopWidth = resWidth
MsRdpClient.DesktopHeight = resHeight

MsRdpClient.Width = resWidth
MsRdpClient.Height = resHeight
MsRdpClient.server = "<%=fqdn%>"

MsRdpClient.AdvancedSettings2.RDPPort = "3389"
MsRdpClient.Connect

sub MsRdpClient_OnDisconnected(disconnectCode)

history.go(-1)

end sub
```